# Distance matrix is not returning distance for large data

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to return the distance eith google Distance Matrix Service. It returns the distance for 60-100 data. But for large data more than 100, it does not works. What I have done is,

```
   var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService(); 
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [origin],
    destinations: [dest],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
```

This is inside loop.

the call bac function is :

```
  function callback(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
    var results = response.rows[i].elements;
    for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
    var element = results[j];
    var distance =(parseFloat(element.distance.value)/1000).toFixed(1);
    var un = '';
    if($('input[name=distance-units]:checked').val()=='kms'){
    un = themiles;
    } else {
    un = thekm;
    }
    var duration = element.duration.text;
    var from = origins[i];
    var to = destinations[j];
    arr.push(distance);
    }
    }

    distancecode++;
    if(distancecode==(totalrec+1)){
    distancecode=0;
    arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
    for(k=0;k<=arr.length;k++){

    $('#d_'+(k+1)+' .value').html(arr[k]);

    $('#d_'+(k+1)+' .units').html(un);
    }
    arr = [];
    }
    } 
    }
```

I don't think there is error in code as it is working for small data. So how can I make sure the function retuns data for large data. Is there any way. I searched for it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453387/google-distance-matrix-zero-results-returned) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348351/google-distance-matrix-gives-different-distance-for-altered-source-and-destinati). It described problem different than mine. Thank you. Any kind of help are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit to the number of origins times destinations that results can be returned for:

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#quotas)

> ## Quotas#
>
> The following usage limits are in place for the Distance Matrix service:
> Note: each query sent to the Distance Matrix service is limited by the number of allowed elements, where **the number of origins times the number of destinations defines the number of elements**.
>
> Maximum of 25 origins or 25 destinations per request.
> Maximum 100 elements per request.